# How to ad a title on a section of my wordpress blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to ad a title "Instant Independent" to the center "featured" section of my wordpress blog. Directly above where the "fee increase coming soon for lake mohave" story. http://www2.az-independent.com/

How do I do this?

Comment: You should provide a link to your blog so we can take a look.

Comment: You're using a premium theme, you should seek support from the theme authors(we can't help with code we can't see). Dan's answer is accurate unfortunately..(unfortunate in the sense that we can't get at the code to help you).

Comment: more over, start asking wordpress questions on [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) it's part of the family now ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please list some HTML in your question so we can see what's going on.  Link-based questions _will_ become obsolete if your website goes down for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

You do so by editing one of your theme files and adding that text. That's as much as anyone can tell you given the information you've provided.